# Python, append list and yield result to a file, scrapy

Tags: python, for-loop, scrapy, yield

New to python, coming from javascript.

I am trying to append to the `plates` list using a for-loop and then yield the result to a file - but I think that the yield keyword is firing before the appending happens.  I am not entirely sure though if that is actually the problem.

Should I use `global`?  Should I use `asyncio`?

Not sure if it is relevant but this is a scrapy project initiated with `scrapy crawl data_spider -o data_spider_results.json:'jsonlines'`

Thanks for any help!

```
class DataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'data_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.scraped-site.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.scraped-site.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//table[2]')
        plates = []

        for tr in table.xpath('.//tr'):
            b = tr.xpath('.//b//text()')
            name = b.get()

            ingredients = []
            p = tr.xpath('.//p//text()')
            ingredients.append(p.get())

            plate = {"name": name, "ingredients": ingredients}

            plates.append(plate)

        yield plates
```

Comment: `yield` is used in generators in python, is that really what you're trying to do here? The placement of the `yield` makes me think that you're looking for `return` instead?

Comment: That seems to have worked.  I guess I am misunderstanding yield.  I thought it was pythons version of javascript's return.  Ill have to research further.  Thank you!

Comment: @Matt Python has a `return` that is like the `return` from JavaScript. JavaScript also has `yield` which is similar to `yield` in Python. And as Alexander says, `yield` is the correct thing to use here because it is required by the `scrapy` library.

Comment: @HampusLarsson  There is nothing wrong with the OP's use of yield.

Comment: @Alexander I never said there was, however I was correct in that it caused the behaviour that confused OP.

Comment: @HampusLarsson  How?  What do you think changing from a yield to a return did to make the OP's code work the way they wanted it to?

Answer (score 1):

You can only yield a `scrapy.Item`, a `dict`ionary, or a `request` object from any of the parse callbacks when using scrapy.

There is no issue with your use of `append`.

You would probably be better off yielding each individual plate especially since you indicate that your are using jsonlines format in your scrapy command.

For example:

```
class DataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'data_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.scraped-site.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.scraped-site.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//table[2]')
        for tr in table.xpath('.//tr'):
            b = tr.xpath('.//b//text()')
            name = b.get()
            ingredients = []
            p = tr.xpath('.//p//text()')
            ingredients.append(p.get())
            plate = {"name": name, "ingredients": ingredients}
            yield plate
```